# Missing .dll in different Visual Studio versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I recently came up with an issue. I had a project created on visual studio 2015, using allegro5 library which executed on Debug and Release mode correctly.

When I changed visual studio versions though and started using 2019 version (In the mean time I had to format my PC and re-installed **only** VS19) and loaded the project, the execution had a missing msvc110d.dll error shown up.

I tried to find a way in order for my project to be "upgraded" and instead of looking into the old version of msvc to try and look up the newer version, but couldn't find anything.

So is there a way for me to change some settings in order for my project to expect newer versions of msvc, or do I have to create a new project and copy paste all the configurations and files/assets inside that new project?

Thank you all

P.S I know that the error can be resolved If I get the .dll file inside that directory, but that is bad practice for sure. Also could you give me a tip on how to setup a project correctly in order to prevent those kind of issues in the future?

Comment: Surely you meant msvcr110d.dll.  It is the debug CRT for code that was built with VS2012.  So yep, you don't have it anymore.  Rebuilding the library with the provided cmake files is the way to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried to rebuild the whole project, but it still needed the msvcr110d.dll (yeap I misspelled it, sorry for that). Is this what you are saying or am I missing something else...

Comment: @HansPassant You misunderstood me, I tried to rebuild my project (it's not that big and doesn't take time to rebuild), that's why I thought I might be missing something from your explanation. When you say rebuild the library, what do you mean? The allegro5 library? That came straight from the allegro5 site.
(Also the 2nd one was fun as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to find the VS2015 redistributable on Google and install it on your machine. That should solve it.

Comment: I did download the redistributable and copy paste it on the debug folder and it worked, but I know that this is a messy solution and would really like a more official/clean one

Comment: Your main issue is that the alegro5 library you are using is built on an older compiler. And I am guessing you cannot build it for VS2019 since you don't have the source. One thing you can try is to reduce your Platform toolset version for your project down to vs110. However, I am not sure you get that low a version default on VS2019. Probably you will need to download the right Windows SDK for it.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the fastest and most convenient way is to  download and install [Visual C ++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) directly.

Comment: @user3389943 Thank you for the explanation! I realized that after some time yesterday! Anyway I'm trying to build the allegro5 library again with the current VS version, but I get some errors on the building stage.

Answer (score 0):

Windows dynamic library files are installed under c:\windows\system32 directory. A 32 bit dll file in a 64 bit windows can be found under c:\windows\syswow64. When your VC++ developed application searches for the dll it first checks in the application folder and then the system folder. If it is not found in these locations, a "missing dll file" error will be shown.

Normally, installing the right VC++ redistributable does the trick. But at times the mismatch persist as the sdk you're using is not in conformity with the system dll. You shouldn't replace the existing dll in the system directory manually with a downloaded( download only from www.microsoft.com) one as other installed software may also failed in the process.

In such worse case scenario, you can however directly copy the downloaded dll files  in your application folder itself and distribute along your software so that it runs on a remote host too. Normally these compatible dll files, for both debug and release versions, are also available in your VC++ sdk directory which can be copied for a perfect match.

Comment: Thank you as well for your answer, Is there a way though on my current project, through configuration settings or another way to make my project look for the current VS19 .dll's ?

Comment: Copy the required dll files to your application folder directly since installing VC++ redistributable don't work in your case Check these missing dll files in your VC++ sdk directory.

Comment: Since the project executes on your developer computer, these matching dll files are available , so search for them for custom distribution along with your software.

Comment: Hmm, I have already identified which are the ones missing and as a 'first' solution I did copied the missing one on the same directory folder as the executable. But this seems to me a bit messy, so is there a way to fix this via using configuration settings from the project to target the newer VS version?

Comment: As alternative you can try changing the target sdk under project settings.

Comment: The target sdk under the project settings is configured on the latest Windows 10 configuration, but It didn't solve the issue unfortunately...

Comment: But under windows 10 different versions such as 10.2317 sdk exist. Also you can install additional components of VS

Comment: I know, my initial problem was that I have in the past created a project with VS2015 on Windows 7, in the meantime I have formated on Windows 10 and installed VS2019 and now the project (which was previously developed on windows 7 VS2015) doesn't run because I no longer have VS2015 installed on my PC.